# Visual Studio 2019 not starting after update

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In our development we used Visual Studio 2019 16.4.x up until now and everything worked fine. Now Visual Studio urged us to update to a newer version (tested versions 16.5.1 to 16.5.4) and after the update it's not working anymore.

Some colleagues can't even start Visual Studio anymore. I can at least start Visual Studio but will see the same error message like my colleagues sooner or later.

The error messages translates to something like: "The file or assembly "netstandard, Version 2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" or one of it's dependencies could not be found"

Repairing the installation or re-installing Visual Studio 2019 didn't help.

What went wrong in the update of Visual Studio and how can we get it running again?

Googling for this specific error message didn't result in helpful finds, it looks like we are the only ones with this problem.

UPDATE: One colleague seemed to be an early adopter of Visual Studio 16.5.x and had no problem until he updated his Windows 10 today.

Comment: No change at all with versions 16.6.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently other developers installed a Microsoft libary to the GAC. The installed version of this library is linked to .NET Standard 2.1. But since Visual Studio 2019 works with .NET Framework 4.71 and .NET Framework 4.71 doesn't work with .NET Standard 2.1 and Visual Studio 2019 also works with the library our developers installed, Visual Studio 2019 crashed whenever ist wanted to work with this library (which seems to be quite often). Exchanging the installed version of this library for an older one did the trick, Visual Studio 2019 works again.
The library in question was "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll".